# Mail program for Netbook

Tags: software-recommendation, ubuntu-netbook, email

What mail programs fit on a netbook screen?

Evolution isn't bad, but To, CC, and BCC are in fact too much.

- Chris

Comment: Evolution provides the option to disable CC and BCC fields. When writing a mail look in the view menu.

Comment: I am neither satisfied with Evolution nor Thunderbird performancewise. I am trying sylpheed at the moment.

Comment: What are your requirements? HTML? Calendar? GUI? IMAP/POP? etc.. Almost all can be tweaked to get the most out of the available space...

Comment: @Detnuomnu: IMAP and GUI. No HTML. Console would be okay too but even Pine needs more configuration and manual reading than I'm about to spend.

Comment: no calendar or html with gui. Evolution and TB are bloated then. Go with either claws, sylpheed or the promise of postler (see answer jnv). Mess around in preferences to get most out of vertical space.

Comment: I installed Claws and like it very much! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Thunderbird, IMO, is much better than Evolution. For example, you can make the buttons smaller, or even remove the ones you never use, and arrange parts of the interface however you want to save a ton of space. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are plans for "Evolution Express" as interface for smaller screens, however it's a [work in progress](http://live.gnome.org/Evolution/Art).

[**Claws Mail**](http://www.claws-mail.org/) is a very good client (it was forked from [Sylpheed](http://sylpheed.sraoss.jp/en/)). If you get over somewhat "oldskool" interface (which can be customized to look better), you get mature, very lightweight and responsive client.

**Postler** looks very promising, but it's in early stages of development - see [this post](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/postler-elementary-e-mail-application-released/) for screenshots and installation info.

Note that Mutt works great at 80x24 chars console - or even smaller. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that [Postler](http://elementaryos.org/discover/) is pretty good. It's made by the same people who have made Elementary OS, judging by the screenshot I've seen of it, it looks very clean and fresh looking.

Answer (score 0):

My personal favourites are [Claws](http://www.claws-mail.org/) and [Thunderbird](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/).